# C++ - Ship script dependencies together with the application

Tags: c++, packaging

Is it a good practice to include script files (with application logic etc) in a final application?
We have an application written in C/C++, but some of the parts of this app call our scripts which we obviously need to provide to a client.
Same goes for interface files. We do not compile them but provide client with xml.

Comment: what are 'script files'?

Answer (score 0):

There are no good alternatives to providing all files that are needed for software to work.

Compiling translates program source code to platform-specific machine code. Main reasons why compiled machine code is harder to read than source code is that it is reorganised into fewer files, some optimising transformations are applied to it and all the names, comments and formatting is lost too.

There are tools, (search for "obfuscator",) that do similar things with scripts. It is possible to find such tool of relatively passable quality for majority of popular script languages.  However beware that it will make some of your defects (or defects caused by obfuscator) trickier to troubleshoot.

That can make both your and your customer life harder and your progress slower ... hard to call it good practice.